# Pass Database URL using package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm passing the URL STRING Using `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "set DB_PORT=53345 && set MONGOLAB_URI='mongodb://localhost/ivr' && node server.js" 
}
```

**Console Output**

```
console.log(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI)   //  'mongodb://localhost/ivr'
console.log('mongodb://localhost/ivr')  // mongodb://localhost/ivr
```

Error:

```
Error: Invalid mongodb uri. Must begin with "mongodb://"
      Received: 'mongodb://localhost/ivr'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try This Way

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set DB_PORT=53345&&set MONGOLAB_URI=mongodb://localhost/ivr&&node server.js"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the single quotes surrounding the mongodb uri:

```
set MONGOLAB_URI=mongodb://localhost/ivr
```

BTW you can do:

```
"start": "DB_PORT=53345 MONGOLAB_URI=mongodb://localhost/ivr node server.js"
```

Comment: I'm using windows OS